# Is it possible to connect local django project to MySql running on AWS EC2? How?

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-ec2, mysql-python, django-mysql

What I tried:

- Installed the MySql server on the EC2 instance.
- In the security group of the instance added an inbound rule to connect over shh from all source
- Created a database and user
- Given that user all permissions using `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
- Created a Django project using `django-admin startproject mysite` and installed mysqlclient
- in project settings, I changed the default database from SQLite to

```
{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbtest',
        'USER': 'root',
        'HOST': '{IPv4 Public IP of the Instance}',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
}
```

Now when I run `python manage.py runserver` it gives me the error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)")
```

Then I granted all privileges to this specific IP as well using: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Still no luck.Same Error.

Comment: Did you add MySQL port in security group ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to set MySQL configuration for allowing it to accept remote connection in mysqld.cnf file add change following value.

```
[mysqld]
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
# skip-networking
```

then restart MySQL Service.

and you also have to add **Application port** in Security Group of EC2 instance